# flash javascript don't work (Second try)

Tags: javascript, flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [flash javascript don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495497/flash-javascript-dont-work)

javascript:

```
function getFlashMovieObject(movieName)
{
  if (window.document[movieName]) 
  {
      return window.document[movieName];
  }
  if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet")==-1)
  {
    if (document.embeds && document.embeds[movieName])
      return document.embeds[movieName]; 
  }
  else // if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet")!=-1)
  {
    return document.getElementById(movieName);
  }
}

function TestPlay()
{
    var flashMovie=getFlashMovieObject("myFlashPlayer");
    try
    {
        document.getElementById("TimeDisplay").innerHTML=flashMovie.GetDuration();
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        alert(e.message);
    }
}
```

html:

```
<object width="150" height="100" id="myFlashPlayer">
<param name="movie" value="Sound.swf"/>
<embed src="Sound.swf" width="150" height="100" name="myFlashPlayer">
</embed>
</object>
<button onclick="TestPlay()" id="TestBtnPlay">Play</button>
<span id="TimeDisplay"></span>
```

AS 2.0:

```
_global.track=new Sound();
_global.track.onLoad=finished;
_global.track.loadSound(Path.text,true);
_global.last_position=0;
_global.track.stop();

ExternalInterface.addCallback("GetDuration", GetDuration);
stop();

function finished()
{
_global.track.stop();
}

function GetDuration()
{
    return _global.track.duration;
}
```

Comment: You should edit your original question: [flash javascript don't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495497/flash-javascript-dont-work)

Comment: i took a diffrent approch so i wanted it to be a new question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function TestPlay()
{
    try
    {
        document.getElementById("TimeDisplay").GetDuration();
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        alert(e.message);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is don't make sense, GetDuration it's a flash functionm and TimeDisplay it's an HTML element. why should this work??

Comment: It make all sense. All you are doing in that line is telling your js to get your flash object id="TimeDisplay". Once you have your flash object all you have to do is access the function you exposed by using "ExternalInterface.addCallback("GetDuration", GetDuration);" Have a look on the AS2 reference: http://flash-reference.icod.de/

Comment: 1. my falsh id is "myFlashPlayer", you probably means that

Comment: 2. i forgot a line in the code i wrote here (in TestPlay) I'm fixing it right now...

Comment: yes, sorry. Thats what I meant. I guess now it makes more sense!

Comment: what the diffrence from what i've already done? going between frames is working fine with the 'flashMovie' variable. so the function 'GetDuration' supose to work too, no?